# shell script without password

Tags: command-line, scripts

I am executing following steps to mount my server and copy the files.
But it interrupts for password. How can I do it automatic ?

```
sudo apt install cifs-utils 

sudo mount -t cifs -o user=user.name //192.168.X.X/BAfolder  /media

cp -r /media/BAfolder/* /home/techy/Documents/files/
```

Comment: If it is for the cifs password, there is an option to mount.cifs `-credentials=filename`, where you may put username, password and windows domain name (see `man mount.cifs`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the password in a file with highly restricted permissions in a restricted folder that only you can access. Cat the file out and pipe the output to `sudo -S` instead of plain sudo.

```
cat <folder>/file.secret | sudo -S mount -t cifs -o user=user.name //192.168.1.21/BAfolder  /media
```

store the password in a shell variable `export password=X` and then echo it

```
echo $password' | sudo -S mount -t cifs -o user=user.name //192.168.1.21/BAfolder /media
```

Comment: hello, 
I mounted my smbfs witht he above command 'sudo mount -t cifs -o user=user.name //192.168.1.21/BAfolder  /media' 
But it is not executing on other system. I is showing me the options I can do with mount command. like man mount.
What can be problem ?

Comment: You run that same command on the other machine? Can you post a pastebin.org link to what you are seeing please? I believe you will want to open another post unless it is related to your original problem too.